# How To Prevent My Mat Buttons From Disappearing When Disabled?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am dynamically disabling my Mat Buttons (https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples) using an expression bound to `disabled`. I.e. `[disabled]="buttonNum+1!=curTask"`.

When the buttons should be disabled, they disappear completely. I verify this by hard coding `[disabled]="true"` or `[disabled]="false"`.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Of course, I want the buttons to look like the disabled ones at the bottom of [this](https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples) demo page when `[disabled]` is set to true. I don't want them to fully disappear like they are now.

Comment: please share your code on stackblliz

Comment: It's weird. Check your styles, maybe somewhere you have something like this: 
button: disabled {display: none;}

Answer (score 2):

if you have a dark theme then disabled buttons wont appear on a white background and vice versa, check if this is the case